# Abel's five terms relation from Yang-Baxter equation?

Tags: reference-request, qa.quantum-algebra, special-functions, quantum-groups

Can the famous Abel's five terms relation satisfied by the dilogarithm be derived from (a particular case of) the theory of Yang-Baxter equations? 
If yes, how?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Quite a well-known paper [Quantum Dilogarithm  L. D. Faddeev, R. M. Kashaev](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9310070)
discovers that in an appriate limit  the q-exponential function degenerates to 
dilogarithm. (It might be suprising dilogorithm and q-exp were known for more that 100 years, but the relation between them have been uncovered in 1993).

Moreover the authors show that five-term dilogarithm identity is a limit of the identity for the q-exponential functions. The last identity in contrast to the classical one, includes non-commuting variables.  It is related in certain sense to Yang-Baxter  (star-triangle)  equation, however it seems not quite direct relation, although it is clearly from the realm of Yang-Baxter quantum group theory.
 I also  heard that similar identities for q-exponential function appear in 
the proof that certain construction of universal R-matrix indeed satisfies the Yang-Baxter equation.

[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_dilogarithm) might be quite useful. The so-called "quantum dilogarithm" now appears in many papers on quantum Teichmuller theory (see papers by Fock,Rosly, Chekhov, et. al. on arXiv e.g. [The quantum dilogarithm and representations quantum cluster varieties V. V. Fock, A. B. Goncharov](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702397))